# Refactoring my verbose C# MVC Search Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC action that accepts search criteria from a search form(dropdowns and a textbox) that returns a list of items based on the search criteria.But I am not satisfied with the outcome because code is too lengthy/verbose. I want to refactor it. Any suggestion where I can get the same result but my code not messy like this? I dont need an exact copy of my code, I just want a simpler format to achieve the same result. Any idea? Look at this mess.

```
public PartialViewResult ClientSearch(ClientViewModel data) {
    var model=new ClientViewModel();

    //get all clients if dropdowns and searchstring is null / nonselected
    if ((data.SelectedLocation==null) && (data.SelectedClientStatus==null) && (data.SearchString=="" || data.SearchString==null)) {
        model.ClientsCollection=_ClientService.Get(null, null, "ClientsProfile, ClientsMobiles").ToList();
        return PartialView("_ClientsResult", model);
    }
    //get clients based on searchstring if no dropdown is selected but searchstring is not null/blank
    else if ((data.SelectedLocation==null) && (data.SelectedClientStatus==null) && !(data.SearchString=="" || data.SearchString==null)) {
        model.ClientsCollection=_ClientService.Get(u=> u.FullName.Contains(data.SearchString), null, "ClientsProfile, ClientsMobiles").ToList();
        return PartialView("_ClientsResult", model);
    }
    else if (data.SelectedLocation==null && !(data.SelectedClientStatus==null) && (data.SearchString=="" || data.SearchString==null)) {
        model.ClientsCollection=_ClientService.Get(u=> u.StatusID==data.SelectedClientStatus, null, "ClientsProfile, ClientsMobiles").ToList();
        return PartialView("_ClientsResult", model);
    }
    else if (!(data.SelectedLocation==null) && (data.SelectedClientStatus==null) && (data.SearchString=="" || data.SearchString==null)) {
        model.ClientsCollection=_ClientService.Get(u=> u.LocationID==data.SelectedLocation, null, "ClientsProfile, ClientsMobiles").ToList();
        return PartialView("_ClientsResult", model);
    }
    else {
        model.ClientsCollection=_ClientService.Get(u=> u.LocationID==data.SelectedLocation && u.StatusID==data.SelectedClientStatus && u.FullName.Contains(data.SearchString), null, "ClientsProfile, ClientsMobiles").ToList();
        return PartialView("_ClientsResult", model);
    }
}
```

My main concern is the if else statements because I am creating another dropdown in my search form and it will add a bunch of lines of conditions in my controller action..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public PartialViewResult ClientSearch(ClientViewModel data)
{
    var model = new ClientViewModel();
    model.ClientsCollection = _ClientService.Get(u => ((data.SearchString == "" || u.FullName.Contains(data.SearchString)) && (data.SelectedClientStatus == null || u.StatusID == data.SelectedClientStatus) && (data.SelectedLocation == null || u.LocationID == data.SelectedLocation)), null, "ClientsProfile, ClientsMobiles").ToList();
    return PartialView("_ClientsResult", model);
}
```